# vue-router showing blank page when built

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I'm asking for help. I use vuejs to make my application. Everything works perfectly. But I do the  `npm run build`, I extract the dist folder and I open index.html, I have a blank page, and when I look in the console, I have no errors.

## main.js

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import router from "./router";
import App from "./App.vue";
import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";
import store from "./store";
import {
  ValidationObserver,
  ValidationProvider,
  extend,
  localize
} from "vee-validate";
import fr from "vee-validate/dist/locale/fr.json";
import * as rules from "vee-validate/dist/rules";

// install rules and localization
Object.keys(rules).forEach(rule => {
  extend(rule, rules[rule]);
});

localize("fr", fr);

// Install components globally
Vue.component("ValidationObserver", ValidationObserver);
Vue.component("ValidationProvider", ValidationProvider);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

//load vue-moment
Vue.use(require("vue-moment"));

//Load vuex
Vue.use(Vuex);

//Load vueRouter
new Vue({
  router,
  vuetify,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

## router/index.js

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Professeur from "../components/Professeur";
import Matiere from "../components/Matiere";
import Dashboard from "../components/Dashboard";
import Filiere from "../components/Filiere";
import Salle from "../components/Salle";
import Shedule from "../components/Shedule";
import SheduleLine from "../components/SheduleLine";
import Login from "../components/Login";
import Home from "../components/Home";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/dashboard",
      name: "dashboard",
      component: Dashboard,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      },
      children: [
        {
          path: "personnel/professeurs",
          name: "p_professeur",
          component: Professeur
        },
        {
          path: "",
          name: "home",
          component: Home
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      path: "/login",
      name: "login",
      component: Login,
      meta: {
        guest: true
      }
    }
  ]
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("_GET_TOKEN"));
    if (!user && !user.token) {
      next({
        name: "login"
      });
    } else {
      next();
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

export default router;
```

## App.vue

```js
<template>
  <v-app>
    <router-view/>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'app',
  }
</script>
```

Once I compile, I have no errors but a blank page.

Thanks for any help. I tried without the router view, I manage to launch the index.html once compiled for production and I have a rendering.

Comment: But if I didn't use vue-router in my project, it works fine.

Comment: You might need to add more information. Node is not likely to be the issue here

Comment: @evolutionxbox like what ? like what ? Add the code of my router and main.js?

Comment: Anything that can help us understand the issue. Nodejs is pretty much required (unless I’m mistaken) for running and building Vue apps.

Comment: I don't know if with the code I added, if it can help you?

Comment: Adding code _always helps_, even if it doesn't help me (I don't know vue).

Comment: I edited the title to better reflect the issue you're having

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using `history` mode for your router, which means you'll access your pages with paths like `/login` or `/dashboard` or `/dashboard/personnel/professeurs`, which are the only routes you declared.

`/` or `/index.html` does not display anything because the router doesn't know what they are.

However, in order to have `history` mode working, you cannot just have a static server. The server has to know that a request to `/dashboard` should return the `index.html` file.

If you used VueCLI, the [docs here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#routing-with-history-pushstate) might be helpful:

> If you are using Vue Router in `history` mode, a simple static file server will fail. For example, if you used Vue Router with a route for `/todos/42`, the **dev** server has been configured to respond to `localhost:3000/todos/42` properly, but a simple static server serving a production build will respond with a `404` instead.
>
> To fix that, you will need to configure your production server to fallback to `index.html` for any requests that do not match a static file. The Vue Router docs provides [configuration instructions for common server setups](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html).

If you don't want to deal with this, or don't have a server enabling you to do this, you can switch `history` to `hash` mode in your router. Your routes will be accessible at `/index.html#/dashboard` and so on.

Comment: Yes i use vue-cli to create my project.

Comment: VueCli docs says that non-existing routes in HTML5 mode will lead to error 404. However, it's not the case. I'm getting blank page instead of 404, exactly as the topic starter. This page is Vue's index.html with no content rendered. Since I'm using SPA ASP.Net Core Middleware, which is kind of web server for the Vue, I would expect that Vue's non-existing routes would be caught by other endpoints defined in ASP.Net Core, e.g. `endpoints.MapControllerRoute`, which is desirable in my case. It doesn't work. It seems like Vue Router intercepts all URLs completely.

Comment: So, if Vue Router takes control over URLs completely I don't understand a reason why we need rewrite URLs on a server. Why not to rewrite them in Vue Router.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running into this issue (as I was) in 2022 with a **serverless vue 3 application** and vuex, you can configure the hash-histroy like so

```
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from 'vue-router'
import { type RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router'
import { Admin, Welcome } from '/@/views'

const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Welcome',
        component: Welcome
    },
    {
        path: '/admin',
        name: 'Admin',
        component: Admin
    }
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHashHistory(), // <--- this is important
    routes
})

export { router }
```

See also: [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#createwebhashhistory)

Answer (score 0):

router/index.js :

```
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from 'vue-router'
import HomeView from '../views/HomeView.vue'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: HomeView
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'about',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/AboutView.vue')
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router
```

main_folder/vue.config.js

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  lintOnSave: false,
  publicPath: ''
})
```

Important: use `publicPath: ''` and `createWebHashHistory`

That is all. You can now build. But remember that your links will appear as `/index.html#/dashboard`.