# After create the build. while runing build showing blank white page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, deployment, build, onesignal

After running the `yarn build` getting the dist folder. While running the `index.html` I am getting the white blank page.

**File structure:-**

```
:~/Desktop/web$ ls  

    babel.config.js  docs  node_modules  public     src            yarn.lock
    dist             log   package.json  README.md  vue.config.js
```

**vue.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: "./", 
    chainWebpack: config => {
      config.plugins.delete('prefetch');
    },
    devServer: {
        host: 'localhost',
        https: false,
        port: 8080, 
        public: 'localhost'
    },  
}
```

**Web Page Output:-**

[image]

**Console Output:-**

```
OneSignalError.js:18 Uncaught (in promise) f: OneSignal: This web push config can only be used on https://example.com. Your current origin is http://localhost:8080.
    at Function.checkRestrictedOrigin (https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalPageSDKES6.js?v=151508:1:243516)
    at Function.<anonymous> (https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalPageSDKES6.js?v=151508:1:243076)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at r (https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalPageSDKES6.js?v=151508:1:716)
GET http://localhost:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1632898657676 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
GET http://localhost:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1632898659676 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
GET http://localhost:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1632898662675 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had spent a lot of time on this issue, at last, I got the solution. on list post https://stackoverflow.com/a/60239175/13178120. if you are getting this type of error you can go through with the above link.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are testing OneSignal with your local server from Vue, but you have entered in the OneSingal configuration corbid360.com as your URL. What you have to do to test OneSignal is to change the URL inside of the OneSignal dashboard to the local server from your Vue project. Once you have tested it in your local environment, you can change it back to corbid360.com

Most likely the reason is that you need to specify to OneSignal that you are using localhost.

1. Select Typical setup
2. Enter your localhost URL
3. Enable Local Testing
   (Treat HTTP localhost as HTTPS for testing)

[image]

Come join us in our discord server and learn more about our community and OneSignal: https://onesignal.com/onesignal-developers

Comment: Do you think due to this OneSignal error I am getting the blank build? if yes then I am confused when I am running the with the port like `yarn serve` on that time I am getting the same issue but not getting the blank white page. what can be the reason behind that?

Comment: This error only I am getting while building the app when I am running the build `index.html`.

Comment: I have fixed the OneSignal Error But still, I am getting the blank white screen while running the build file.

Comment: If you are not getting an error from OneSignal, I doubt OneSignal is the one giving you the issue on the white screen. Have you tried commenting out OneSignal code and see if you get the white screen too?  BTW OneSignal has an npm package fro vue https://www.npmjs.com/package/onesignal-vue

Comment: I have commented on the code also has created the new build with 'yarn build'. I am still getting the white blank page.

Comment: ahh yes then sounds like it's not a problem with OneSignal then. No errors in your console then?

Comment: yes, now I don't have an error in my console. is there any way to find the issue?

Comment: did you check your vue terminal where your server is running? or just the console inside of the browser?

Comment: I am checking in both. console and terminal.
`yarn run v1.22.5
warning ../../package.json: No license field
$ vue-cli-service serve`

Comment: this is I am getting on the terminal and the console is clear there on any warning.